# Add Text to Chart Series

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, charts, data-visualization

I have a WinForms DataVisualization Chart that I'd like to add text to in the actual chart data. I am wondering if this is possible, since there is no `SeriesChartType` which is text.
I am constantly writing new data to the graph during a test sequence and a single test sequence consists of several tests. In my attached image, you will see that I use a red circle to indicate the beginning of a new test in the test sequence. I would like to change the circle, or append to it, a description (such as a single letter) to help differentiate each test when reviewing the data.

```
Series newSeries = new Series("currentValues"); // graphs black line 
newSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
newSeries.BorderWidth = 1;
newSeries.Color = Color.Black;
newSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chtCurrent.Series.Add(newSeries);

Series newSeries2 = new Series("newTestIndicator"); // graphs red circle
newSeries2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
newSeries2.BorderWidth = 1;
newSeries2.Color = Color.Red;
newSeries2.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
chtCurrent.Series.Add(newSeries2);
```

[image: current_time_chart]
*please ignore the placement of the bottom +/- buttons*

Comment: You can add a ToolTip to each DataPoint you like. Also there are Annotations of various types including Text, I think. and you could use the Paint events to write onto the Chart or to modify the annotation objects or labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to TaW for pointing me in the right direction. Each `DataPoint` has a `Label` property which writes text beside the point. Works exactly as needed.